# map multiple callback returns into observable using RxJs

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

I'm currently beggining with RxJs and trying to define modules returning observables. (each module works as a blackbox and only exposes its observables).
my main problem is due to the third party library I'm using : UWA :
All my dom elements are generated from UWA objects and trigger UWA "events".
BTW I want to map those custom events to observables.
here is a part of the event data structure :

```
tabBar = *somecode*...{
....
  onEndEditTab: function (callback) {
    return this.modelEvent.subscribe({
      event: endEditTabEvent
    }, callback);
  },....
}
```

Here is my current code :

```
const tabBar = new tabBar();
tabBar.inject(domContainer);
const observer={
  next: (t) =>{
    const oldValue=t.target.textContent;
    const cbObservable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(tabBar.onEndEditTab);
    //a new cbObservable is created at each dblclick event
    // (due to bindCallBack property which is to retern only one time.
    cbObservable .call(tabBar).subscribe(
      (v) => {
         console.log({oldLabel:oldValue,newLabel:v[0].button.label});
      }
    );          
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(tabBar, 'dblclick').subscribe(observer);
```

This code works and log the old and new value each time a tab label is edited.
But currently what I want instead of just printing this is to aggregate all those results into a new Observable stream.
using marble diagram :

```
dblclick : ----(1)----(2)---....(n)->
```

(where there is an unknown number n of dblclick...)
is mapped to :

```
cbObservable : ----(1:{old,new})--|
               ----(2:{old,new})--| 
               ....
               ----(n:{old,new})--|
```

And what I currently want is :

```
outputStream : ----(1:{old,new})---(2:{old,new})--...(n:{old,new})--->
```

where outputStream is an hot observable; 
is there a way of doing that with all constraints described above ?
thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use switchMap

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(tabBar, 'dblclick').switchMap(() => {
    const oldValue=t.target.textContent;
    return Rx.Observable.bindCallback(tabBar.onEndEditTab).map((v) => {
       return {old: oldValue, new: v[0]}
    });
})
```

or something like this, then make single subscribtion to resulting observable

Comment: according to the definition : `bindCallback` is not an operator because its input and output are not
   * Observables. The input is a function `func` with some parameters, but the
   * last parameter must be a callback function that `func` calls when it is
   * done.

So the question  is more, how to convert this output into an observable ?

Answer (score 0):

**@llCorvinuSll** : thank you for your answer, after one simple modification it was working :

adding call(yourObject) to the bindCallback !
bindCallback return a function, so it need to be called :

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(tabBar, 'dblclick').switchMap(() => {
    const oldValue=t.target.textContent;
    return Rx.Observable.bindCallback(tabBar.onEndEditTab).call(tabBar).map((v) => {
       return {old: oldValue, new: v[0]}
    });
})
```